# Solution to Recursive Relations with Arrays

Tags: algorithm, recursion, relation

from Mexico. The truth is almost never asked or open new issues, because really the forum and not only this, if not to work instead of the network, you can find plenty of information about topic x or y, however this time I feel very defeated.
I have two years of recursion.

1. Define the following recursive algorithms.

a. Calculate the next n integers.

At first not referred to the master with this is that if the algorithm returns a sum, or set of numbers. Furthermore, although in principle and algorithm design for the second case is asked to resolve by its expression as a recurrence relation ... this is where I am more than lost, not how to express this as a RR. And that can be solved

b. Calculate the minimum of a set of integers

In the other case suppose that calls for the minimum of a set of integers. that's solved, but the fact and pass it to a RR fix, has left me completely flooded.

APPRECIATE ANY HELP, thanks

Comment: Perdon, la pregunta no esta claro. Puedes tratar a simplificar la pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Answering on b)

You have a set of integers. You pick one and you know that minimal element is either that you've picked or the minimal is still in the set. Recursivly you call function unless you pick all elements from set, you assume that minimum of set that contain no elements is infinity. Then your recurrence is going back updateing the minimal value.

minimum (S) = min(any element, minimum(Rest of S))
if (S is empty) then minimum(empty) = infinity.

Not an implementation in any language cause surely depend on representation of set.

P.S why doing this recursivly?